# How to run an executable file that uses MS Access within an Ubuntu container?

Tags: c#, docker, ubuntu, ms-access

I'm trying to run an executable (.exe) file run inside an Ubuntu Docker container via Mono. However, the function of this executable file is to query a MS Access DB file (.accdb) and save the results to a CSV file.

As expected, cross-platform issues occur.

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: ole32.dll

I've been rummaging the internet for ways to make it run in an Ubuntu environment but so far, the solutions I found are to modify the code to use another DB provider instead.

Unfortunately, modifying the executable file is out of scope.

Is it impossible to run on Ubuntu?

Comment: Access / MDAC doesn't seem to be on [the list of database providers in Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/)

Comment: Mono doesn't provide native MDAC driver support, sounds like it's necessary using emulators like Wine to run MDAC.

Comment: I tried using Wine and it still doesn't work. Basically, this use case, as of this time, is not doable.